# Display Sidebar and Pages based on the User Role in Laravel 5.1

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.1, user-roles, login-attempts

I am Using the Same Login Box and i am Differentiating the Users after Login using **Auth::attempt()** function. In my project i have only one Sidebar which Contains all the Menus that are required for my project.

I have Four Login roles namely Admin / Teaching Staff / Non-teaching Staff / Parent.

My doubt is that i need to display only some menus and related Blade(Views) that are inside that Sidebar Menu for different login users.

Screenshot Attachment:
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhTtH.png)

I dont need to Redirect the Page based on the Login Users i need to alter my display based on Login Attempts.

I have not used any Packages for Authentication i am using only Auth::Login and Auth::attempt() functions.

Can you please provide me with a Solution of how to Get rid of This Error for Me.

Answer (score 0):

How i would do it is `Auth::check()` and then i would do if statement with elseif

So it would look like this

```
@if($User->Role == 1 )
    Nav Items for Admin 
@elseif($User->Role == 2)
    Nav items for Teaching Staff 
@elseif($User->Role == 3)
    Nav Items for Non-teaching Staff
@elseif($User->Role == 4)
    Nav Items for Parent
@endif
```